# Accessing IEnumerable clears content

Tags: c#, cassandra, ienumerable

I've got a database (Cassandra) query that returns an IEnumerable. Trying to track down why this was returning no data (when I know there's data in the database) I found a curious issue.

The query does in fact return data, 25 entries. I was checking this with a Data.Count(); But later in the code, it was empty. I realised that the Count Method was inexplicably clearing the data.

After a quick investigation: Any for of reading this data clears it completely. Even in the debug, if I load the "results view" to get the list of data, initially I see my 25 entries - then if I click off, and then reload the results view: Emtpy.

Anyone ever had anything like this before?

```
        String connectionString = "SELECT * FROM thedatabase WHERE thecondition";

        RowSet Data = ExecuteComand(connectionString);

        if (Data == null) // interestingly, I can check for null without issue
        {
            OutputMessage("Output to " + exportFile + " failed");
            return;
        }
        int b = Data.Count(); // results in 25
        int c = Data.Count(); // results in 0
```

Comment: Not familiar with Cassandra and its connector, so not sure why it is doing that. Probably a performance tuning so the query is just executed once? I don't know if it suits you but have you tried to materialise the IEnumerable? That is var data = Data.ToList(), and work with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know cassandra but i assume that the returned `IEnumerable<T>` is executed lazily(deferred). By consuming it (f.e. with `foreach`, `ToList` or `Count`) the query gets executed and the resources(f.e. the connection) are disposed/closed.

If that's the case you could load it into an in memory collection, for example:

```
var data = ExecuteComand("SELECT * FROM thedatabase WHERE thecondition").ToList();
```

Now you can use  `data.Count` without "clearing" it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that a `Enumerable` can be enumerated twice. A correctly built enumerable should at least throw an exception, but bad code could always happen. What you can do is materialize it in a well-behaved collection, a `List<T>` for example:

```
var data2 = Data.ToList();

int b = data2.Count;
int c = data2.Count;
```

Now you even have the advantage that `Count` is O(1) instead of O(N) :-) (in a `List<T>` the `Count` value is "cached")

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I'll have to bear that in mind with Enumerable in future. Thanks